# XmlConvert.ToDateTime Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to convert an xmlattribute's value (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzzzz) to yyyyMMdd.

I'm trying to use:

XmlConvert.ToDateTime(xmlattribute.Value, "yyyyMMdd")

But i'm getting formatexceptions:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Any help is very much appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ToDateTime` returns a DateTime not a formatted string as you seem to want.

Try:-

```
 string formattedDate = ((DateTime)xmlattribute).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the format exception because you are telling the formatter the string is "yyyyMMdd" but it is in fact "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzzzz".

What you need to do is create a dateTime object using the value, then get a string back from the dateTime object in your desired format using the ToString(...) method. E.g.

```
  DateTime dateTime = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(xmlattribute.value);
  string result = dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

**edit**

According to the MSDN docs the `XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string)` method is deprecated in favour of `ToDateTime(String, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)`. Docs are http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todatetime.aspx

Suggest you try

```
    DateTime dateTime = XmlConvert.ToDateTime
        (xmlattribute.value, 
         XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Unspecified);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but when i use the ToDateTime method i get the error: "No overload for method 'ToDateTime' takes 1 argument"

Comment: Hmm. OK, I'll add an edit... not sure why you see this though, it *should* be supported.

Comment: Thanks, works fine. Also for another use i need to convert the DateTime string to be displayed as the long date etc. 20101030 into 30th october 2010, how would i do this? Thanks

Comment: Cool:-) The MSDN docs for DateTime.ToString() should cover this.